# Get images from video in c#

Tags: c#, video, frames, aforge

I am using AForge.Video.FFMPEG for getting the images from avi video file in C#.I am using the **videoFileReader** to read the frames from video.

I have added the dll file for the aforge.video.ffmpeg in my project but I am getting error while running my project.

[This is the reference link I am using.](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d3528599-8bf2-f041-d9f9-96c2204c1c2a.htm)

I am getting error:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."
```

while running this project.

Can anyone help me in this

Comment: Thanks Jakub,can you please help me

Comment: Have you added the FFMpeg native dlls as mentioned in the doc you linked to ?

Comment: In the general case, to debug these type of errors you use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Open the offending file in it, and it should tell you exactly which dependencies are missing.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio you need to make a reference to the dll in your project
As this dll is not part of the default .net files or system32 dlls

this is how you make a reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-KK7bmo1AM